# Placing Images and Div Elements Next to Each Other?

Tags: html, css, image

Working on a page for my website and I'm trying to set up a series of profiles side-by-side. 
[The idea is that the images of the profiles will be external links, but I would like each small block profile to be side by side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtBEh.png)
I'm fairly uncertain of how to do this, ass I thought fixing the padding and adding inline to the blocks themselves would stack them side by side. Help?

```css
.Head, .Welcome {
    padding-left: 300px;
 margin-right: 150px;
}

.body {
    padding-left: 300px;
 margin-right: 150px;
}

.img.center {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 200px;
 background-color: #d9d9d9;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 display: inline-block;
}

li {
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}

#pagename {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Arial"
}

li a {
 display: block;
 color: #000;
 padding: 8px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: "Arial"
}

.active {
 background-color: #990000;
 color: white;
}

li a:hover {
 background-color: #990000
 color: white;
}

#titletext {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Arial";
 font-size: 50;
}

/*GAR PROFILE*/

.Gar{
 padding-left: 300px;
}

.gar-block1{
 background-color: #990000;
 color: white;
 font-family: "Arial";
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 250px;
 padding: 20px;
}

.gar-block2{
 background-color: #d9d9d9;
 color: black;
 font-family:"Arial";
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 250px;
 height: 300px;
 padding: 20px;
}

/*MAYU PROFILE*/

.Mayu{
 padding-left: 750px;
 display: in-line;
}

.mayu-block1{
 background-color: #990000;
 color: white;
 font-family: "Arial";
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 250px;
 padding: 20px;
 display: in-line;
}

.mayu-block2{
 background-color: #d9d9d9;
 color: black;
 font-family:"Arial";
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 250px;
 height: 300px;
 padding: 20px;
 display: in-line;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html>
<!--HEAD INFORMATION-->
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CHARACTER_PAGE.css">
  <title>FFXIV RP Database</title>
  <style>
   div.head {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    padding: 20px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
<!--END: HEAD INFORMATION-->
 
 <body>
<!--NAVIGATION BAR-->
  <div class="Navigation">
   <ul>
    <li id="first"><img src="xiv logo.png" width="200px"></li>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="characters.html" class="active">Characters</a></li>
    <li><a href="story.html">Story</a></li>
    <li><a href="stats.html">Stats</a></li>
    <li><a href=".html">Contact</a><li>
   </ul>
  </div>
<!--END: NAVIGATION BAR-->

<!--HEADER-->
  <div class="head">
   <h1 id="titletext">FFXIV RP Database</h1>
  </div>
<!--END: HEADER--> 

<!--BELOW HEAD CONTENT-->
  <div class="Characters">
   <p>
    <h2 id="pagename">Characters</h2>
    <p>
  </div>
 
<!--CHARACTER PROFILE: GAR-->
 <div class="Gar">
  <p>
   <a href="https://charahub.com/character/1024524/Gar"><img id="garprofile" src="Gar.png" height="290px"></a>
    <div class="gar-block1"><h3>"Gar"</h3></div>
    <div class="gar-block2">
     <p><b>Age:</b> 30</p>
     <p><b>Height:</b> 5'11"</p> 
     <p><b>Job:</b> Dark Knight</p>
     <p><b>Role:</b> Tank</p> 
     <p><b>Family:</b> Unknown mother and father (estranged)</p> 
     <p><b>Significant Other:</b> Mayumi Mori</p> 
 </p>
<!--CHARACTER PROFILE: MAYU-->
 <div class="Mayu">
  <p>
  <aside>
   <a href="https://charahub.com/character/1024524/Gar"><img id="garprofile" src="Mayumi.png" height="290px"></a>
    <div class="mayu-block1"><h3>Mayumi Mori</h3></div>
    <div class="mayu-block2">
     <p><b>Age:</b> 23</p>
     <p><b>Height:</b> 4'8"</p> 
     <p><b>Job:</b> Astrologian</p>
     <p><b>Role:</b> Healer</p> 
     <p><b>Family:</b> Junko Mori (Dead) and Khaguran (Unknown)</p> 
     <p><b>Significant Other:</b> Gar</p> 
  </aside>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is incredibly invalid. You're missing a bunch of closing tags, have elements in `p`'s that shouldn't be there. You should run this code through a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/), fix the errors, then see if you can figure it out. You might also [validate your CSS](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). That will tell you, for example, that `display: in-line;` isn't valid - it's `display: inline`. The HTML needs to be fixed before you can tackle the layout problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if i can understand you well here but did you mean that you want the profile to be centered?

If this is the case, i already made it for you.

Please also check your html code, there are lots of missing `</>` close tag

I also edit some of your codes, please check the codes below both HTML and CSS.

Since `.Gar` and `.Mayu` are same layout, i made the css layout of it in one class `profile` display both container `inline-block`

Hope it helps.

```css
    div.head {
        background-color: #000000;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .Head, .Welcome {
        padding-left: 300px;
        margin-right: 150px;
    }

    .body {
        padding-left: 300px;
        margin-right: 150px;
    }

    .img .center {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: #d9d9d9;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    li {
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
    }

    #pagename {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "Arial"
    }

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: #000;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: "Arial"
    }

    .active {
        background-color: #990000;
        color: white;
    }

    li a:hover {
        background-color: #990000 color: white;
    }

    #titletext {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "Arial";
        font-size: 50;
    }

    /*GAR PROFILE*/
    .profile {
        margin-left: 300px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .block1 {
        background-color: #990000;
        color: white;
        font-family: "Arial";
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        width: 250px;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .block2 {
        background-color: #d9d9d9;
        color: black;
        font-family: "Arial";
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 250px;
        height: 300px;
        padding: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<!--NAVIGATION BAR-->
<div class="Navigation">
    <ul>
        <li id="first"><img src="xiv logo.png" width="200px"></li>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="characters.html" class="active">Characters</a></li>
        <li><a href="story.html">Story</a></li>
        <li><a href="stats.html">Stats</a></li>
        <li><a href=".html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--END: NAVIGATION BAR-->

<!--HEADER-->
<div class="head">
    <h1 id="titletext">FFXIV RP Database</h1>
</div>
<!--END: HEADER-->

<!--BELOW HEAD CONTENT-->
<div class="Characters">
    <p>
        <h2 id="pagename">Characters</h2>
    </p>
</div>

<!--CHARACTER PROFILE: GAR-->
<div class="profile Gar">
    <p>
        <a href="https://charahub.com/character/1024524/Gar"><img id="garprofile" src="Gar.png" height="290px"></a>
        <div class="block1">
            <h3>"Gar"</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="block2">
            <p><b>Age:</b> 30</p>
            <p><b>Height:</b> 5'11"</p>
            <p><b>Job:</b> Dark Knight</p>
            <p><b>Role:</b> Tank</p>
            <p><b>Family:</b> Unknown mother and father (estranged)</p>
            <p><b>Significant Other:</b> Mayumi Mori</p>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>

<!--CHARACTER PROFILE: MAYU-->
<div class="profile Mayu">
    <p>
        <aside>
            <a href="https://charahub.com/character/1024524/Gar"><img id="garprofile" src="Mayumi.png" height="290px"></a>
            <div class="block1">
                <h3>Mayumi Mori</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="block2">
                <p><b>Age:</b> 23</p>
                <p><b>Height:</b> 4'8"</p>
                <p><b>Job:</b> Astrologian</p>
                <p><b>Role:</b> Healer</p>
                <p><b>Family:</b> Junko Mori (Dead) and Khaguran (Unknown)</p>
                <p><b>Significant Other:</b> Gar</p>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use float:left; in your css style sheets.

```
#a{
float:left;
}
#b{
float:left;
}
```

this two divs whith id : a , b  will be side by side but you need to use clear:both; in next div;Remember about closing tags  .I hope it helps